# Python Regular Expression Filtering by Prefix

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Regular Expressions are a bit counter-intuitive, in this case I'm going through a kernel in kaggle for the titanic.

There's a name field with the passenger's name

```
#Looking how the data is and searching for a re patterns
df_train["Name"].head()
```

results

```
0                              Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1    Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...
2                               Heikkinen, Miss. Laina

3         Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)

4                             Allen, Mr. William Henry

Name: Name, dtype: object
```

he then proceed's to create a new column to analyze the prefix of the users

```
#GettingLooking the prefix of all Passengers
df_train['Title'] = df_train.Name.apply(lambda x: re.search(' ([A-Z][a-z]+)\.', x).group(1))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

#Plotting the result
sns.countplot(x='Title', data=df_train, palette="hls")
plt.xlabel("Title", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Count", fontsize=16)
plt.title("Title Count", fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

This creates this graph

[image]

considering the example first names shown by the column, they don't necessarily start with the name of the Mr, Mrs title. So in general I'm curious what is created with this lambda function

```
df_train['Title'] = df_train.Name.apply(lambda x: re.search(' ([A-Z][a-z]+)\.', x).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It searches for the sequence of characters(the first is a capital letter) followed at least by a low-capital character('+') that starts with a space and ends with a dot(since dot is a special character, it uses \ before it)